# How to align columns in foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have finally started to use foundation and it's great. So I was just testing out an example and I noticed that if only have two columns in a row it looks like this:

[image]

I would have thought that "Box B" would have been next to "Box A". How do I align it to the left?
I haven't read too much into the documentation (as I should be), but I thought I'd ask.

In case you needed the code (the code is given when you download foundation):

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="large-4 columns">
         <div class="panel">
             <p>BOX A</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <p>BOX B</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 11):

You can add the .end class to column B to get it to align to the left.

```
<div class="large-4 columns end">
    <div class="panel">
        <p>BOX B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: http://scotch.io/tutorials/css/understanding-zurb-foundation-5s-grid-system

Answer (score 3):

This is because the base Foundation grid has to add up to 12.

> The columns are created using the css classes: .small-#, .medium-#, and .large-#. The #s have to add up to be 12 since Foundation uses a 12 grid system.
>   Source: http://scotch.io/tutorials/css/understanding-zurb-foundation-5s-grid-system

Change the classes to large-6

Answer (score 1):

Check your css for `class="row"` and add `{float:left;}`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Keep in mind I am using the foundation framework.

Comment: Pleas try

`.row div
 {
  float:left;
 }`

Comment: Nah it sorta screws up the other elements.